# Non-standard Delay differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I am trying to solve the following system of ODEs:

```
pfun = NDSolve[{exp[-1]*exp[-x]*Dg[InverseFunction[g][f[x]], x] - exp[x] + f[x] == 0,exp[-x]*Df [InverseFunction[f][g[x - 1]], x] - exp[x - 1] + g[x - 1] == 0, f[x /; x <= 0] == 0, g[x /; x <= 0] == 0},{f, g}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

But I keep getting responses like "The function f appears with no arguments."

I am trying to solve the system as delay differential equations, but the problem is that my system is not the standard delay differential equations since the delayed variable $x-1$ and the current variable $x$ never appear in the same equation.

Any recommendation on how to solve this issue?

Comment: 1) If `exp` is the exponential, then is should be uppercase (`Exp[x]`). 2) What are Dg and Df? 3) I don't think you can impose boundary conditions using `;/`.

Comment: Dg and Df is taking derivative with respect to x.

The ;/ command is what I get from the NDSolve syntax for delay differential equations.

Even if I switch the boundary condition to the usual one like f[0]==0, g[0]==0, I still get notification "The function f appears with no arguments"

Comment: The derivative of the inverse function of g[x] is given by: 1/(g'[ InverseFunction[g][x] ]). But note, inverse functions may be tricky because they can be multivalued.

Comment: Yeah, these equations are reached by taking derivative on inverse functions.